# Как можно получить псевдослучайную последовательность бит в python?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Как можно получить псевдослучайную последовательность бит в python с помощью встроенного модуля random? Можно ли использовать для этого `bin(random.getrandbits(k))`? В документации написано ,что эта функция выдает псевдослучайное число ,полученное из вихря Мерсенна ,но будет ли двоичная запись это числа считаться двоичной псевдослучайной последовательностью ? Нужно это для работы с пакетом тестов NIST

Comment: Вы имели в виду getrandbits? Ну лично я не вижу причин, почему бы это не считать псевдослучайной последовательностью бит. Но я бы взял [secrets.randbits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.randbits) для более случайной случайности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да,можно. Для большего качества последовательности можно использовать secret.randbits() (по совету из комментов )

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: @0xdb прошу прощения,но как я могу дополнить свой ответ?(просто не очень понимаю )